# C# SharpDX device E_OUTOFMEMORY exception when loading a large scene

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, sharpdx

I am writing a SharpDX (v4.0.1) application that displays assemblies composed of many (possibly very big) separate parts. Each part has its own vertex and index buffer. When I try to load a very big assembly, I eventually run into E_OUTOFMEMORY exception when trying to create a vertex buffer for a part:

```
int size = _meshVertices.Length * Utilities.SizeOf<MeshVertex>();
BufferDescription descr = new BufferDescription(size, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
_vertexBuffer = Buffer.Create(_device.Device, _meshVertices, descr);

$exception  {"HRESULT: [0x8007000E], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_OUTOFMEMORY/Out of memory], Message: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.\r\n"}  SharpDX.SharpDXException
```

When I was googling a possible solution, I found out that there is a size limit on a resource - but this doesn't seem to be the case as it happens even for smaller parts.

Another solution I tried was using the MemoryFailPoint class to try to reserve the memory before creating the buffer. But I suppose this checks for available RAM, while I believe the exception is caused by having not enough GPU memory. Anyway, this seems to alleviate the problem a bit but it doesn't fix it completely. It just takes longer before it fails.

```
int size = _meshVertices.Length * Utilities.SizeOf<MeshVertex>();
using (System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint memFailPoint = new System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint(size / 1024 / 0124))
{
    BufferDescription descr = new BufferDescription(size, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
    _vertexBuffer = Buffer.Create(_device.Device, _meshVertices, descr);
}
```

My problem is that after I get the exception, the device is lost. I assume that the resources such as vertex buffers are bound to the device, so to recreate the device after it is lost would mean to recreate all the resources which would be very time consuming.

So preferably, I am looking for a way to know that the device does not have enough memory before I try to create the buffer, so that I could just discard the single part if needed. Is it possible to do something like that?

Any help would be very much appreciated. I am new to SharpDX so if you think I misunderstood the problem and something else is causing it, please let me know as well. Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Comment: You are right that this is a GPU memory issue - what is the value of `size`?

Comment: Well, for the big assembly I have, it fails on a different part every time I run the program. I tried running it three times now, and the size (when it threw the exception) was 1374912 the first time, then 766080 in the second run and 3415776 in the last run.

Comment: The individual sizes look ok - ranging from 750KB to 3.4MB - so that's not the issue. Are you properly disposing of _vertexBuffer (and every other SharpDX disposable type) when you create a new one?

Comment: I have many separate models that I need to render all at once, so I have a vertex buffer for each of them and I switch them for rendering. I cannot discard them because then I would have to recreate them for each frame I render.

Comment: Take a look at [Resource Limits for Direct3D 11- and 9-level hardware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819065(v=vs.85).aspx) and [for 10-level hardware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308052(v=vs.85).aspx). Those show the limits for numbers of and size of vertex buffers, and you can calculate how that compares with your GPU's VRAM.

Comment: Well, ok, I understand GPU memory limits but my question is if there is some way to know that I am about to reach the limit before I actually hit it and the creation of the vertex buffer fails.

Comment: My experience is that even when you discard of the managed object (and thus the COM object underneath it), the graphics driver often seems to hold onto memory for some unspecified amount of time, leading to E_OUTOFMEMORY errors when it looks like there should be enough memory. You can track how large `size` gets and how many buffers you have created.